# com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git overloading CPU

Tags: xcode, git, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm noticing that Xcode is severely affecting my computer's performance. I can only have Xcode open for a few minutes at a time before everything I have open starts slowing down and my computer starts overheating. When I check Activity Monitor, there are usually 5-15 lines that say "com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git". Sometimes my app won't get past the landing page until I force quit them all. Has anyone come across this before? Are there any settings I can change to make this stop?

- Xcode version: 7.1.1
- OS version: 10.11.1
- Happens in Swift and ObjC

[image]

Comment: How much RAM does the computer have?

Comment: 16 GB and about 6.7 GB used

Comment: That sounds good, I have seem 4GB Macs thrash to swap. By any change do you have any memory monitoring turned on?

Comment: No I just check Activity Monitor for my memory usage. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Your computer starts overheating? What does that mean? Unless you are overclocking, the computer should drop into power states (P or T) that will reduce performance preventing overheating.

Comment: Why have you revived this by editing it? Are you still having this issue?

Comment: yeah it happens almost everyday. it's not in this screenshot but most of the time it's a bunch of those "com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git"s, kernal will be over 100% cpu, my computer slows down tremendously and the fan is working on overdrive. Sometimes it will crash Xcode and make all of the other apps unresponsive but it resolves the problem a few minutes after i force quit Xcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into Xcode's Accounts preferences and delete all Git repository info there.

Comment: Thanks! I just did. I had a lot of unused repos in there. Hopefully that will fix it!

Comment: Pls do report back on how this turns out.

Comment: I can't see any Git repository info on Accounts! I went to Xcode Preferences > Accounts.

Answer (score 10):

For Xcode 10.1: preferences > Source Control > remove all automatics sych

it has a large effect on your CPU usage